# Best practice? JNDI, Hibernate and Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jndi

I've got a web application, hosted with tomcat, which uses hibernate to talk to a database.

I'm looking at how I can easy the pain of configuration as I migrate from dev, to test and to prod.

I've seen JNDI mentioned a lot and at first glance it seems like a good idea. You configure a jndi resource on each tomcat instance and the web context just uses it.

However after examining it further it seems that in order to have a JNDI I've got to have all my database objects + hibernate in the tomcat lib files in order for this to work. This sounds scary to me, what if I want to deploy another context that uses a different version of hibernate?

Also, am I not just swapping the pain of maintaining configuration for the pain of breakages caused by mismatches between the installed jndi resource classes and the ones in my context.

Ideally I think what I'm wanting is to just say in tomcat. There is a database called X, it is at this server and has this user/pass.

I'd appreciate your thoughts on the best way to handle the need for different config in different environments without having an extra step after each deploy to update the config files.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 2):

You have confused things a bit, I believe.

JNDI is just a name assigned to a datasource pool. This datasource uses a JDBC driver which in global Tomcat classpath, but that about the only shared resource in the whole setup.

Datasource has connection URL, username, password and options for connections defined, which may differ per server, but application doesn't care about it -- all it knows is the JNDI name, e.g. "jdbc/myDatasource".

All hibernate JARs, and well as any other JARs and whats not are to be packaged within the WAR. They are "visible" only within the WAR, and therefore you can have multiple applications using conflicting versions of libraries deployed to the same Tomcat.

No need to pollute lib/ directory of Tomcat. This is a bad practice, as you correctly observed.

Comment: So the instructions here (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJNDI-boundSessionFactorywithTomcat41) are a bad idea?

Comment: Also, assuming I can work out how to create my session factory as something that talks to the jndi datasource, how do I deal with the issue of my dev environments using mysql and test/prod using SQLServer?

Comment: The instructions there are how to use SessionFactory via JNDI. In other words, how to share Hib SF between a few applications. I do not see how "it is very useful", so my advice is to share only the necessary minimum, which is datasource.

Comment: You're using different not even versions, but RDBMS in dev and prod? Well... this is quite an adventure, eh? What you can do though is to place hibernate.cfg.xml into Tomcat global classpath. The rest of files will still be within WAR.

Comment: Hmm, now there's an idea. Might move away from the default name and call it mycontext-hibernate.cfg.xml. I'll report back and let you know how I go.